# How can this Ruby loop be more efficiently expressed?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb, mongoid

I'm coming from a PHP world and pretty new to Ruby, so there may be a better way to do this. Could this block be more succinctly expressed with better code?

```
bands = Band.where(:type => 'Rock & Roll').only(:id)
band_ids = bands.map &:id

band_ids.each do |id|
  lead_singer = LeadSinger.find(:band_id => id)
  if lead_singer
    lead_singer.rock_and_roll = true
    lead_singer.save
  end
end
```

It all feels a little bloated. The "if lead_singer" part I added in case no result was found, but if there's a better way to go about this, I'd love to be enlightened.

**EDIT**
I'm using MongoDB with Mongoid, so joins won't be an option for me.

Comment: `LeadSinger.find(Band.where(:type => 'Rock & Roll).pluck(:id)).update_all(:rock_and_roll => true)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With MongoId you should still be able to update with criterias:

```
LeadSigner.where(:band_id.in => band_ids).update(:rock_and_role => true)
```

Comment: Should you not add the multi flag here?

Comment: Using the scope.update, mongoid should set the multi flag itself.

Comment: That works... thanks. Thanks again as always for your MongoDB insights @sergio

Answer (score 4):

Answer for ActiveRecord (before question update, still useful I hope): make associations: a Band has_one :lead_signer, A LeadSinger belongs_to :band. And now:

```
LeadSinger.joins(:band).where(:"bands.type" => 'Rock & Roll').
  update_all(:rock_and_roll => true)
```

Comment: I like the update_all, but I should've mentioned I'm using MongoDB w/ Mongoid and can't use joins

Comment: @jnunn: if you don't mention the ORM it's assumed to be AR. Update the question then. I've no experience with MongoDB, though.

Comment: Thanks @tokland, it's updated now--still upvoting your answer